# Laravel deployment using Google App Engine: No such file or directory

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible) tutorial and created a database under the name `zoho_portal`. My `app.yaml` contents are:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

# required on some platforms so ".env" is not skipped
skip_files: false

    env_variables:
      # The values here will override those in ".env". This is useful for
      # production-specific configuration. However, feel free to set these
      # values in ".env" instead if you prefer.
      APP_LOG: errorlog
      STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
      CACHE_DRIVER: database
      SESSION_DRIVER: database
      ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
      DB_HOST: localhost
      DB_DATABASE: zoho_portal
      DB_USERNAME: USER
      DB_PASSWORD: PASS
      DB_SOCKET: /cloudsql/zoho-portal-159018:us-central1:zoho-portal 

    beta_settings:
        cloud_sql_instances: "zoho-portal-159018:us-central1:zoho-portal"
```

I have also added this to my `composer.json`:

```
"post-deploy-cmd": [
    "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache"
]
```

However, after deploying this using `gcloud app deploy`, and visiting the website at: https://zoho-portal-159018.appspot.com/, I receive this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from
>   `sessions` where `id` = iq8isoeEqTaj5xVNmVm0JuFKtR8vtSEB0ajJl23o limit
>   1)

As far as I can see, I haven't missed any of the steps listed in the tutorial and the database is set up correctly. I also don't think it has anything to do with database migration. From what I can tell, this is an issue with how the socket file is set up.

Comment: I'm struggling with this also

Comment: I just posted this on [GAE Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/5hbsOv36qvU). Let's hope someone there gives a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with using database as the session driver. The temporary solution is to use another driver (memcached, redis) etc

Comment: Could you please demonstrate on how to use a different driver?

Comment: Go to config -> session.php on the line ['driver' =>] paste 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),